# cycle divs in jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a `<div>` wrapped inside a container with `overflow:hidden` activated. 
i have seven other `<div>` placed at the bottom of the wrapper, hidden. 
there is one `<more>` button which animates the current `<div>` to hide and the next `<div>` to show up.

I am trying to imitate [nikebetterworld UI](http://nikebetterworld.com). my main concern is how to cycle the `<div>` so that one goes up and the other comes up in its place. then the second one goes up and the next one takes its place.

Can someone help?

Comment: you are aware of this: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is animation chaining: http://blog.gridworlds.com/js/animation-chains-with-jquery

Comment: it looks like nike is scrolling the background at the same time as they are scrolling to a content div.

Comment: the effect i am pointing towards is the one near the "more" button.